# Flask send html data back to view

Tags: python, post, flask, request, jinja2

I am creating a page with a list created by a jinja for loop.
I want the user to make a selection of an item on that list.
I want that selection to send the user to that items page as well as send the selected item back to my python code for further processing.

In my 'home.html' page i have the following:

```
{% for item in list %}
    {{ item }}
    <form method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' value='select'>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in my python view:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    list = ['a','b','c']

    #???????????????????????????????????????????????
    selected = request.form.item

    return render_template('home.html', list=list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle the `GET` and `POST` methods separately in your `home()` route.  Something like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected = request.form.item
        # on this line you can process the selected item, but you haven't
        # stated how you'll do that, so I don't know what to display here
        return redirect(url_for('item_page.html', item=selected))
    else:
        list = ['a','b','c']
        return render_template('home.html', list=list)
```

Obviously, I've also assumed that you have a template item_page.html which you use to display that individual item the user selected.  If not, substitute whatever template you will be using there.  You'll also need an `@app.route` for processing that template.